# Steps to ensure our TFS 2012 deployment is robust and recoverable from disaster

Tags: tfs, backup, disaster-recovery

Our TFS2012 deployment is currently quite simple:
Virtual Windows Server with TFS, Sharepoint, Reporting, SQL Server and Builds all on the same machine!

Is using the TFS admin console backup tool and/or backup of the entire machine enough to recover from a disaster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clear-cut criteria, you may take a look at [TFS planning and disaster recovery guidance](https://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/) for a more comprehensive answer.
Shortly, you must be sure at least that

1. Backups are saved on different hardware, and possibly copied to a remote location
2. Along with your backups you have the recover instructions and install packages

This guarantees that you are able to recover, but it can take a long time, depending on the disaster impact (someone deleted a record vs. the server room has burnt) and the size of your data.